# using IDataErrorInfo in WPF and Silverling

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have used *IDataErrorInfo* interface to take care of validation in Model and it works in Silverlight. Same interface is used for the same WPF application, the app works OK but validation is not working.

Am I missing something? my assumption was that the app should work in both platforms but I guess it is not true. any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: How is it not working? Can you provide the code that is not working?

Comment: i used this one for both platforms, and i can say it works fine.

Comment: "Not working" is rather vague.  Please provide a code sample